# Hidden div displays for a split second (slideToggle / javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, slidetoggle

I have a script that hides a div by default and slideToggles it when I click a link (see http://zarin.me -- the contact link). Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact-drawer").hide();
    $(".toggle-drawer").show();

    $('.toggle-drawer').click(function(){
    $("#contact-drawer").slideToggle();
}); 
});
</script>
```

My problem is that when the page loads, the whole div is displayed for a split second, and then hidden. This can be a bit a jarring sometimes. What do I need to fix so that the div doesn't display on load?

Comment: It doesn't show for a split second in chrome. What browser are you testing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Darko Z said below, the reason for this flickering is that there is a delay between the browser rendering the `#contact-drawer` element and your JavaScript code running. The browser is doing what it's told by your CSS and HTML and displaying the element, and only *after* that is it indicating the document has finished parsing (DOM ready) and triggering your JavaScript.

There are a few ways to fix this (with varying compatibility). Essentially you need to get code interpreted in between or before the element rendering and the DOM being ready.

**To patch with JavaScript**, you could add an inline script immediately after the element to set it's display to hidden. This code would be executed immediately as the page is interpreted rather than when the DOM is ready. I believe this is the simplest and safest method in terms of accessibility.

Plain JavaScript:

```
<section id="contact-drawer"></section>
<script>document.getElementById('contact-drawer').style.display = 'none';</script>
```

or with jQuery:

```
<section id="contact-drawer"></section>
<script>$("#contact-drawer").hide();</script>
```

---

**To fix with pure CSS** you would set the element's display property to 'none'. Note that with this solution, **if JavaScript is disabled the form will not be accessible.**

**CSS**

```
#contact-drawer {
    display:none;
}
```

---

**To fix with CSS AND maintain a working page when javascript is disabled** you could use an additional `:target` CSS selector and change your link and JavaScript a little. The target selector is [not 100% compatible with older browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t316), but it's more accessible than the plain CSS version above.

**CSS**

Add the same style as above, and a copy setting display to block with the selector `:target`. This makes it so when you navigate to http://zarin.me/#contact-drawer, the :target style will activate and #contact-drawer will display.

```
#contact-drawer {
    display:none;
}
#contact-drawer:target {
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

Change the anchor href from `#` to `#contact-drawer` so that when the link is click, it activates the `:target` selector.

```
<h3 class="contact">
    <a href="#contact-drawer" class="toggle-drawer" style="">
        <img src="img/envelope.png">
        CONTACT
    </a>
</h3>
```

**JavaScript**

Add `return false` at the end of the function to stop the browser navigating to `#contact-drawer` (and activating the `:target` selector) when `.toggle-drawer` is clicked.

```
$('.toggle-drawer').click(function(){
    $("#contact-drawer").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the display none in your CSS, so that way on load it's already hidden, and then jQuery should handle the show.

For Example

```
<style>
#contact-drawer {
display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-drawer").show();

    $('.toggle-drawer').click(function(){
        $("#contact-drawer").slideToggle();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you are hiding your div on document load which is why you see it for a split second in slower browsers or slower machines.

a far better way of doing this is to hide the div in CSS, which would mean the div is hidden before the document is even shown.

```
#contact-drawer { display: none; }
```

but if you really need to hide it with JavaScript, you can include a script right below your div that executes immediately and not on document ready, this will give you the same effect.

```
<div id="contact-drawer" .... />
<script .... >
    $("#contact-drawer").hide();
</script>
```